# ASP.NET MVC multi-theme support

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, themes

New To .NET and still learning it.
I want to know, how to have multi themes support in my application.
e-g in different websites i change theme from dropdown, theme changes.

how can i achieve such a thing in asp.net mvc 5.

Plus i am using `MVC Areas`.

So i dont want that theme to be applied on the Area, Area Views has its own Layout, so it would be nice to have separate multi theme for MVC Area as the design of area is different from design of main public website..

But for the main site how to achieve multi theme support?

Right now, i have just `Content` Directory with some css files inside, but what should be a better way to structure the content directory for multi theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can express your different themes as different CSS files, then you could put a `switch` block inside your layout view that conditionally includes only the correct CSS reference based on some global theme setting.

Wherever you are including the reference to your CSS file(s), you would check which theme is being used, and substitute the CSS reference for that theme.  Where exactly that is depends on your project.

Comment: thankyou, yes only css will be different in themes as all i want the coloring and some images to be changed, coding will remain the Same.
But right now my content Directory has css files only if i were to create more directories like `js` move fonts directory from outside to inside and create themes directory inside and etc etc.
Where do i put all these references, there is nothing on layout.cshtml, i dont want the nuget packages to mess up also, i mean if i move files inside content, will i still be able to update jquery or etc libraries from nuget.?

Comment: If you change the location of files being tracked by packages like jquery, then that will prevent nuget from properly managing those packages.

Comment: So isnt there any way to tell nuget where the files are, i mean update the path.
i moved fonts directory to content directory plus moved the bootstrap files in the styles directory which resides in Content directory.
it would be much cleaner like this way.
Also Created Themes Directory in Content Directory.

But how to update the paths to the bootstrap files and jquery files for both nuget and header path it self.

Comment: There is probably some way to do that but I don't know what it is, and it's not really related to the question.